# Animate divs to look like they're floating in space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing the following to randomly position a set of divs inside a container without them overlapping:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsd3b0r0/)

```
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }

    .tile {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      background: steelblue;
      margin: 1px;
    }

var tilesize = 18,
  tilecount = 15;
var gRows = Math.floor($(".container").innerWidth() / tilesize);
var gCols = Math.floor($('.container').innerHeight() / tilesize);

var vals = _.shuffle(_.range(tilecount));
var xpos = _.shuffle(_.range(gRows));
var ypos = _.shuffle(_.range(gCols));

_.each(vals, function(d, i) {
  var $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass("tile");
  $newdiv.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': (xpos[i] * tilesize) + 'px',
    'top': (ypos[i] * tilesize) + 'px'
  }).appendTo('.container').html(d);
});
```

How can I make the divs look like they're floating? So just a tiny amount of smooth movement in all directions to make them look like they're floating in space.

**Each div needs to move individually and in several directions (not just left to right or up and down). The directions almost need to be random... I want each one to look like a particle that's floating.**

Comment: you need to add a css animation to the divs -- eg -- http://jsfiddle.net/mfj1pb9v/ -- https://codepen.io/montanaflynn/pen/orxwK  -

Comment: @Tasos I need them to all move individually and not just in one direction.

Comment: What about this? http://old.and-rew.com/space-drew/space-drew.html

Comment: You need to find the appropriate CSS animation from the net that you like. If you want something as fancy as particles then i suggest using a  library like velocity -- http://julian.com/research/velocity/demo.html

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, something like that! (I don't know where to start with that code though!!)

Answer (score 1):

You can do animation following way.

```
var tilesize = 18, tilecount = 15;
var gRows = Math.floor($(".container").innerWidth()/tilesize);
var gCols = Math.floor($('.container').innerHeight()/tilesize);

var vals = _.shuffle(_.range(tilecount));
var xpos = _.shuffle(_.range(gRows));
var ypos = _.shuffle(_.range(gCols));

_.each(vals, function(d,i){
    var $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass("tile");
    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':(xpos[i] * tilesize)+'px',
        'top':(ypos[i] * tilesize)+'px'
    }).appendTo( '.container' ).html(d); 
    animateDiv();
});



function newPosition(){


    var h = $('.container').height() - 50;
    var w = $('.container').width() - 50;

    var newh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var neww = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [newh,neww];    

}

function animateDiv(){
    var newp = newPosition();
    var oldp = $('.tile').offset();
    var speed = 3000;    
    $('.tile').animate({ top: newp[0], left: newp[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

};
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsd3b0r0/1/)**

Comment: That's a bit too much movement, I want it more subtle. Something like this (the way the guy is floating) http://old.and-rew.com/space-drew/space-drew.html but no idea where to start with that code!

Comment: So change the speed.

Comment: @rlemon Is there a way to limit how far away from their starting position they travel? I don't want them flying all over the screen, just moving about 5-10px away from their starting position in random directions.

Comment: @Rob You can change in new position function for that. Make changes in h and w value.